# flutter how do i set a command that my image will not repeat

Tags: flutter, dart

i have multiple image and it will change on every tap but currently the image will repeat.

how do i stop the image to repeat and after the last image is surface, there will have a pop up button.

Thanks in advance

```
class _SettingpageState extends State<Settingpage> {
  List<String> imagelist = [
    'lib/images/image1.png',
    'lib/images/image2.png',
    'lib/images/image3.png',
    'lib/images/image4.png',
    'lib/images/image5.png',
  ];
  late String imagePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    imagelist.shuffle(); //shuffle over here
    var imagePath = imagelist[0]; //store random image over here
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
              height: 600,
              width: 600,
              color: Colors.black,
              child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Center(child: Image.asset(imagePath)),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {});
                  }))),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
class _SettingpageState extends State<Settingpage> {
  List<String> imagelist = [
    'lib/images/image1.png',
    'lib/images/image2.png',
    'lib/images/image3.png',
    'lib/images/image4.png',
    'lib/images/image5.png',
  ];

  late int imageIndex;
  late String imagePath;

  void initRandomImage() {
    imageIndex = 0;
    imagelist.shuffle();
    imagePath = imagelist[0];
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initRandomImage();
    super.initState();
  }

  void showPopUpButton(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('shuffle list'),
        content: TextButton(
          child: Text('shuffle list'),
          onPressed: () {
            initRandomImage();
            Navigator.pop(context);
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 600,
          width: 600,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Center(
              child: Center(child: Image.asset(imagePath)),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              if (imageIndex == imagelist.length - 1) {
                showPopUpButton(context);
              } else {
                imageIndex++;
                setState(() {
                  imagePath = imagelist[imageIndex];
                });
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi hydra , is it possible to have a code before the last image is surface?

Comment: yeah, just do `if (imageIndex == imagelist.length - 2) { // your code }`

Comment: hi, if i would like to change to the pop up button to a image button do i need to rebuild the scaffold and body ?

Comment: not at all, just change what's inside the `AlertDialog`

Comment: hi i have tired using title: IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset

Comment: but there is a white box around my png

Comment: i have tried transparent and there is still a square shade